# Verification Step - determines non empty DE number of records as zero

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

Pls advise - bug or feature:

A Verification step is set up as a first step of 2 different Automations within the Parent BU.
Both Verification steps have identical setup and look at the same shared DE (condition is: if DE=0 records then stop).
Automations are scheduled 1h apart.
DE has records at the time when first automation triggers.

Issue is following:
The earlier Automation recognizes records >0 and proceeds with next steps.
The Later Automations determines the number as 0 and thus stops the process (but records are in the DE - nothing changed there).

The later automation was a copy of the earlier one (if that matters) - the verification step was recreated - still the issue persists.

Running the automations as "Run once" works fine - seems like some issue with scheduling...